# friend function definition and alternative boost function of std::lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, locking

```
class some_big_object;
bool operator<(some_big_object& lhs,some_big_object& rhs);

class X
{
private:
    some_big_object some_detail;
    mutable std::mutex m;
public:
    X(some_big_object const& sd):some_detail(sd){}
    friend bool operator<(X const& lhs, X const& rhs)                   #1
    {
        if(&lhs == &rhs)
            return false;
        std::lock(lhs.m,rhs.m);                                     #2
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_a(lhs.m,std::adopt_lock); 
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_b(rhs.m,std::adopt_lock); 
        return lhs.some_detail<rhs.some_detail;
    }
};
```

**Question 1**> This is the first time I ever see a friend function is defined inside the scope of class. Is it legal?

**Question 2**> what is the alternative boost function for `std::lock`?

I have seen the following usage:

```
boost::unique_lock<MutexType1> l1(m1);
boost::unique_lock<MutexType2> l2(m2,boost::try_to_lock);
if(!l2)
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: First question is answered already, search SO.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but there are the exact same functions in `boost` (the standard ones probably come from there). Though they are not variadic, yet.

You can find them [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.lock_functions.lock_multiple).

```
boost::lock(lhs.m,rhs.m);
boost::lock_guard<Mutex> lock_a(lhs.m,boost::adopt_lock); 
boost::lock_guard<Mutex> lock_b(rhs.m,boost::adopt_lock);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
boost::mutex m;
boost::lock(m); //or unlock
m.lock(); //or unlock again
boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(m);
```

should be the boost syntax.
As I know, boost::mutex and std::mutex are almost same in writing :)